# OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecute)')

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I would like to insert about 400.000 data into SQL Server. But I get error. There is no problem when inserting 5-10 records, but I get this error while inserting the whole csv file.

```
    pyodbc.pooling = False
    server = 'SQLSERVER' 
    database = 'AAAA' 
    username = 'BBBB' 
    password = 'CCCCC' 
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password,MultipleActiveResultSets=True)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
```

OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecute)')

Comment: Maybe a timeout?

Comment: Do your insert per batches. Commit after 1.000 inserts and increase this number or decrease it according to the success of the operation. If you do it per batches, you can reconnect en retry the last X records.